# Cordova/Phonegap Inappbrowser/IFrame can't open Camera on Android

Tags: cordova, iframe, cordova-plugins, phonegap

Running Cordova/Phonegap 6.4.0,Android 5.0, tested with the Inappbrowser and Iframe, Both won't open up the camera but just opened up a Native file selection window. But i need to open up the camera.

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I have had this issue before. It works on some devices and not others. It seem some devices use different webviews which may or may not fully support the camera input in the HTML or they expect a different syntax it seems.

For this reason I recommend using the camera plugin. As this provides a consistent result across all devices.

Cordova File Plugin:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Along with the Cordova File Transfer Plugin:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

If you just want to select images or pictures you can use the Cordova Camera Plugin

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Using this you can enable users to select an image from their camera

Install camera plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Sample camera plugin JS code:

```
var cameraOptions = {

    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
}

function cameraSuccess(data){

    console.log(data);

    var img = document.getElementById("yourImg");

    img.src = data;

}

function cameraError(error){

    console.log(error);

}

navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div><img id="yourImg" src=""/><div>
```

**Original**

Try using this line:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Notice I have include the capture attribute inside the accept attribute.

Comment: Hi, ahh thanks ok! Yer i thought i was doing something wrong.

Comment: Great. If it worked you may want to accept the answer so others know. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is a general solution, but more of a workaround for a specific case. Capturing a photo from a 3rd party page inside the InAppBrowser is still not possible. The suggested workaround involves Cordova and code that I own, instead of 3rd party.